# Can I set my own SSL certificate via .htaccess file in a shared web server?

Tags: ssl, .htaccess, certificate

I am hosted in a shared web (apache) server in a subdomain. I don't have access to any panel, only sshfs.

The problem is that the host (lazy), does not issues / uses SSL certificates.

I issued my own (letsencrypt) but I can't direct the apache to use my certificate. Is it possible via `.htaccess` file?

I tried this in a `.htaccess` file but server is crashing (internal error)

```
SSLCertificateFile "/server_path/user/public_html/letsencrypt/fullchain.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/server_path/user/public_html/letsencrypt/privkey.pem"
SSLCertificateChainFile "/server_path/user/public_html/letsencrypt/chain.pem"
```

PHP info has those values empty: `openssl.cafile`, `openssl.capath`.

I don't know the version of apache. PHP is 5.6.40 (I know: obsolete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. SSL configuration directives can only [be set in the contexts `server config` and `virtual host`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatefile). Not in a .htaccess file.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.